# this binding in an arrow callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

I will appreciate your help and explanation.
I am unclear on the reason why the second and third alerts in the code below are different from the first one.

Arrow functions have lexical binding. This bit is clear.
By why is it that including an arrow function expression as a parameter in an object method call makes a difference for the "this", which somehow gets bound to the global name variable.

```
var name = "globalscope name";

let person = {
    name: 'Tommy',
   
    showName(a){
        let fun1 = ()=>this.name;
        let fun2 = a;
        alert(fun1()); //Tommy - this is behaving as expected base on lexical binding
        alert(a()); // globalscope name - this is not
        alert(fun2()); //globalscope name
    }
}

person.showName(()=>this.name);
```

Comment: Calls to `=>` functions do not bind a value to `this`; that's an extremely important difference between `=>` functions and `function` functions.

Comment: Lexical binding means `this` has the same value in that function as it did when that function was defined. So when this line is reached: `person.showName(()=>this.name);`, this is determined for that function to be equal to the current `this` which is window in non-strict mode.

Comment: Since `this` is not writeable, it can't ever change from that value of `this` no matter how you pass the function around, create aliases, or call it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Lexical binding of `this` means that the `this` value is copied from where the function is declared.

The function declared on the last line is in a scope where `this` is `window`.

The function declared on the first line of `showName` is in a scope where `this` depends on how `showName` is called.

---

The `this` value is copied from the scope where the function is declared, not from  it was immediately before being passed to the function where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

In this code block `person.showName(()=>this.name);` `this.name` is referring to the `window` object where in the window object `name` value is `globalscope name`

And you calling the object method `person.showName` for which you're just passing a function reference along with `this.name (window.name)` due to which `a()` and `fun2()` providing result **globalscope name**